# Losing first buffer when trying to stream recorded audio in AudioQueueNewInput via Websocket

Tags: swift, xcode

I am working on some code to stream audio to a server and it is working fine except I always seem to lose the first 500ms of audio.
My assumption is that the websocket is still opening when the first buffer is sent and then when the next buffer is full and runs the callback, the socket is open.
The websocket is opened like this when the user clicks the record key:

```
    func startRecording() {
        if !connected{
            connect()
            print("Websocket state is: \(webSocketTask?.state.rawValue)")
                startStreaming()
        }
    }
```

I think the issue is here which is in the startStreaming function;

```
            liveRecorder.delegate?.readyRecordingData(audio: audioData)
            liveRecorder.currentPacket = liveRecorder.currentPacket + Int64(inNumPackets)
```

The first time the readyRecordingData is called and audioData is passed, the socket is open but we haven't received the confirmation that the server is ready to receive data which comes in over the websocket.

In the readyRecordingData we do a basic check to make sure we can send the audioData:

```
if (!recordingStarted || !connected){  //connected is set to true when we get ready confirmation from server
 return //since we can't send the data
}
//Send the data here
```

On the first callback, we always have !connected. After that things are fine.
I'm trying to figure out if the first packet is basically lost since we are incrementing the packet here `liveRecorder.currentPacket = liveRecorder.currentPacket + Int64(inNumPackets)` instead of having is queue up and send when ready.
I tried adding a delay if the socket is not open using DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter but that didn't fix it, I tried checking the delegate if the socket is open before sending to the readyRecordingData but that didn't help.
For debugging, I write out a copy of the recorded audio to a file and confirmed that the recording has all of the audio there so it's something to do the first packet.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding code to check the websocket state in the audioQueueInputCallback and if the websocket isn't open, I take the buffer and append it to a NSMutableData variable then put the buffer back in the queue.

```
            audRecorder.audioBufferCallbacks += 1
            audRecorder.bufferQueue.append(audioData as Data) //NSMutableData
            audRecorder.currentPacket = audRecorder.currentPacket + Int64(inNumPackets)
```

I keep appending to the variable until the socket is opened.
When the websocket opens, I send the NSMutableData variable instead of the buffer sent in the callback then clear the variable in case it is needed again.
I also have a check where if the ws isn't opened after receiving x buffers to stop the recording and alert the user so they don't get too far in if any errors occur.